# Nextjs Bootstrap Dropdown issue with server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, next.js, navbar, react-bootstrap, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to build a navigation which has dropdown with few links. It works fine on the browser. But the HTML for the dropdown is not rendered in the page source.

**Navigation Component**

```js
function Navigation() {
    return (
        <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
            <Link href="/" passHref>
                <Navbar.Brand>React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
            </Link>

            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                    <Link href="/" passHref>
                        <Nav.Link>Home</Nav.Link>
                    </Link>

                    {/* Missing html on page source */}
                    <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">
                            Action
                        </NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">
                            Another action
                        </NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Divider />
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">
                            Separated link
                        </NavDropdown.Item>
                    </NavDropdown>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    );
}
```

I'm rendering those navigation from the **_app.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import Nav from "../components/nav";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <>
            <Nav />
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </>
    );
}

export default MyApp;
```

On the page source I get following output:

```html
<div id="__next">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">React-Bootstrap</a><button aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" type="button" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler collapsed"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="basic-navbar-nav">
         <div class="mr-auto navbar-nav">
            <a href="/" data-rb-event-key="/" class="nav-link">Home</a>
            <div class="nav-item dropdown"><a aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="basic-nav-dropdown" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" role="button">Dropdown</a></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </nav>
</div>
```

But I can't see the HTML source of those dropdown related HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `NavDropdown` component will not render its children when mounting, only when it's clicked on. To force the nav items rendering on mount you can set the `renderMenuOnMount` prop to `true`.

```js
<NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown" renderMenuOnMount={true}>
    // ...
</NavDropdown>
```

Comment: Does it have to do with JS in the browser or is it just a HTML-like behaviour? in other words, is it an actual SSR issue or something else? I'd be really glad if you could expand on that

Comment: What's your question regarding to exactly? Whether it renders on mount or not was a design decision, not a constraint.